# Is there a security concern to use **kwargs to initialize a class?

Tags: python, python-2.7, optimization, sqlalchemy

I recently started using `**kwargs` in `__init__()` to initialize an object  as I don't have to do any update to the function when adding another attribute. I just pass them as arguments and the loop do the work.

```
class Customer(Base):
    """Model that defines a customer entity"""

    __tablename__ = "customers"

    date_created = Column(DateTime)
    date_modified = Column(DateTime)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        for key, value in kwargs.items():
            setattr(self, key, value)
```

But, from your experience, is there a security concern by doing so? Can we run into unwanted side effects comparing to the code below that explicitly define what will be initialized?

```
class Customer(Base):
    """Model that defines a customer entity"""

    __tablename__ = "customers"

    date_created = Column(DateTime)
    date_modified = Column(DateTime)

    def __init__(self, attrs):
        self.date_created = attrs.get("date_created")
        self.date_modified = attrs.get("date_modified")
```

Comment: That's almost what the [default `__init__` provided by SQLAlchemy Declarative](https://github.com/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/blob/master/lib/sqlalchemy/ext/declarative/base.py#L653) does anyway, except it checks that the class actually has that attribute before setting. So, just drop the custom `__init__` and use the [default constructor](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/declarative/api.html#sqlalchemy.ext.declarative.declarative_base.params.constructor).

Comment: Thanks @IljaEverilä I dropped the custom `__init__()` in my SQLAlchemy classes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Does this qualifies as "unwanted side effect" ?

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, name, **kw):
        self.name = name
        for k, v in kw.items():
            setattr(self, k, v)


f = Foo("Bob", __dict__={"aaa":1, "bbb":2, "name":"HEHEHE"})
f.name
>>> 'HEHEHE'
```

Or for even more fun:

```
class Bar(object): 
    pass

f = Foo("Bob", __dict__={"aaa":1, "bbb":2, "name":"HEHEHE"}, __class__=Bar)
type(f)
>>> <class '__main__.Bar'>
```

Now as long only trusted code instanciates your class, there's no real security issue here - all this could as well be done outside the initialiser actually. But being explicit makes for more readable code and can help catching a couple typos here and there.

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by Bruno, you can even overwrite `__getattribute__` and `__setattr__`, effectively rendering your class useless

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, name, **kw):
        self.name = name
        for k, v in kw.items():
            setattr(self, k, v)

class Bar(Foo):
    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        return 'no way'   

    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        print('aint gonna happen bro')
```

With this:

```
>>> f = Foo("Bob", aaa=1, __class__=Bar)
>>> f.aaa
'no way'
>>> f.__class__
'no way'
```

You can't even fix it:

```
>>> f.__class__ = Foo
aint gonna happen bro
>>> f.__class__
'no way'
```